# VNC connection times out

Tags: routing, vnc, timeout

I have a VNC server running on a box but can't connect to it over the internet and I don't know why. Here's what I have:

*on server*

```
$ ps ax | grep Xvnc
21304 ?        S      0:00 Xvnc4 :1 -desktop semios-Aspire-V5-571:1 (anthony) -auth /home/anthony/.Xauthority -geometry 1024x768 -depth 16 -rfbwait 30000 -rfbauth /home/anthony/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5901 -pn -fp /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/Type1/,/usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/Speedo/,/usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/misc/,/usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/75dpi/,/usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/100dpi/,/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc/,/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/,/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/,/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/ -co /etc/X11/rgb
24999 pts/13   S+     0:00 grep --color=auto Xvnc
```

*on client (wireshark capture when trying to connect with VNC viewer)*

```
21  7.322833000 192.168.1.121   XX.XX.XX.XX TCP 74  56367 > 5901 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=75810697 TSecr=0 WS=128
38  8.318986000 192.168.1.121   XX.XX.XX.XX TCP 74  [TCP Retransmission] 56367 > 5901 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=75810947 TSecr=0 WS=128
138 10.322993000    192.168.1.121   XX.XX.XX.XX TCP 74  [TCP Retransmission] 56367 > 5901 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=75811448 TSecr=0 WS=128
201 14.330997000    192.168.1.121   XX.XX.XX.XX TCP 74  [TCP Retransmission] 56367 > 5901 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=75812450 TSecr=0 WS=128
```

and then I get a message "*Connection to host semios::5901 was closed.*" But on the router, ports 5900 - 5910 are forwarded to the respective host. What else am I missing?

**EDIT1**

```
$ gvncviewer 127.0.0.1:5901&
[1] 28606
ron@semios-Aspire-V5-571:~$ 
** (gvncviewer:28606): WARNING **: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-lIUigxICjd: Connection refused
Failed to connect to server
```

Comment: Have you tried to connect with a vnc client on the server (using ssh and X forwarding)? Any output from Xvnc4

Comment: Hmmmm....what about firewalls?

Comment: @Anthon I tried to do so, please see **EDIT1** above.

Comment: @mdpc nope, there's no firewall in the path (only the router)

Comment: @cerr I would not necessarily start the viewer in the background. You didn't tell what Xvnc spews out in terminal from which you start that.